# efficient processing of corresponding elements in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays A and B of the same size. I'd need to get the values and indices of items in the arrays according to B's items. Here is my code:

```
promotes = [a for a,b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
demotes =  [a for a,b in zip(A, B) if b == 0]
promotes_index = [k for k,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if b == 1]
demotes_index =  [k for k,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if b == 0]
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to compute promotes, demotes, and the indices.

In more simple words, if A and promotes are like:

```
A = array([ 4,  6,  9, 10]))
promotes = array([4, 9])
```

how could I get promote_index from A and promotes:

```
promotes_index = array([0, 2])
```

I appreciate any response.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` np arrays or lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [`array programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) there to do things in a vectorized manner. We start off by creating boolean arrays corresponding to the conditionals. Then, we use those masks to index into `A` with [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to get `promotes` and `demotes` -

```
mask1, mask2 = B==1, B==0
promotes, demotes = A[mask1], A[mask2]
```

Finally, we use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) on those masks to get the corresponding indices -

```
promotes_index, demotes_index = np.flatnonzero(mask1), np.flatnonzero(mask2)
```

Please note that if `B` consists of `1s` and `0s` only, `mask2` would be simply `~mask1`.